# Inserting Post Using wp_insert_post. How to Fill Yoast Plugin SEO Fields

Tags: query-posts, seo, debug, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, wp-debug

I am inserting posts into a database using `wp_insert_post` function once the post is inserted using below line of PHP

`$postId = wp_insert_post($array)`

I can insert values in my advanced custom fields using `add_post_meta` function but I didn't find anything to insert the SEO title or the meta description specifically in the Yoast SEO plugin.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yoast support ought to be able to tell you the names of the custom fields used. Have you tried their website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function to insert the Yoast Plugin data. Yoast uses 3 post meta keys for each post:

1. _yoast_wpseo_title ( use for SEO title )
2. _yoast_wpseo_focuskw (For meta keywords )
3. _yoast_wpseo_metadesc (For meta descriptio )

You can find all these meta key under postmeta table

```
    $new_id = wp_update_post($array);

    update_post_meta( $new_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', 'SEO Title' );

    update_post_meta( $new_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', 'keyword1 keyword2' );

    update_post_meta( $new_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', 'SEO Meta Descr' );
```

Hopefully, It will work for you!

Thanks

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you! I used it in a loop to populate the info pragmatically to give me a head start on imported woocommerce products.

The problem I'm running into was that I was going to use the yoast color system to see which products needed extra SEO attention but when the values are written this way it doesn't calculate the SEO scores and just give gray circles instead. I have to open a product, then update it to see the score. Not even bulk updating on the backend or looping through products and saving them through a function works.

Comment: does this still work?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla Yep!

Comment: hi,  please have a look at this question : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318704/update-post-meta-not-working-when-used-with-transition-post-status-action